# expat for IronPython 2.7.1 beta 2

Tags: python, ironpython, nltk

I'm trying to get [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org) working with IronPython 2.7.1. The installation works so far, but I tried some sample code and the `expat` module is missing. Any hint how to get that up and running for IronPython? I found some hints on the web, but they are quite outdated (IronPython 2.0) and are using python projects which seem to be dead.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear if FePy's pyexpat works for NLTK. I tried pyexpat for another use, and something didn't work quite right, but I couldn't track down the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version from the old FePy project ([here](http://fepy.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fepy/trunk/lib/pyexpat.py?revision=614)) should still work, but it's incomplete and might not have all of the capabilities NLTK needs.